# C program refuses to pipe?

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, pipe, adventure

I am trying to compile the 1991 C port of the original Crowther/Woods FORTRAN Colossal Cave Adventure. The code is a horrible mess, but after changing certain sections of it it compiles and runs properly.

The problem is that when I attempt to pipe its output to another program or to a file, nothing shows up. `./adventure` works fine, but `./adventure | cat` doesn't print anything. Grepping for a call to `fstat` turns up nothing.

Is there some other way that the program might be detecting the pipe and going into silent mode? Even adding `printf("Hello World");` as the first line of the main function doesn't cause anything to appear through cat.

EDIT: I'm using Jim Gillogly's version, but the link I got the source from has gone rotten. I will find another download link for it.

Comment: It is probably not "going into silent mode".  When stdout is a tty, it is line buffered by default.  When it is a pipe, it is block buffered.  Your data is probably just sitting in the pipe buffer.

Comment: To see this behavior in a simpler program, write a hello world program that prints 'hello world\n' and then goes to sleep for 10 seconds.  Notice the difference in behavior when that program writes to a terminal verses writing into a pipe.  (Make sure you print a newline.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the existing comments have said, stdout is probably block-buffered because it isn't opened to a terminal any more. Try adding the call:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

somewhere around the start of the program. This will change stdout to line-buffered mode, which will flush the output as soon as the program writes a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the program, on Linux you can also experiment with changing the buffer mode from the command line using `stdbuf` (although obviously any `setvbuf` calls in the application will override this). For example, you could try:

```
stdbuf -oL ./adventure | cat
```

A similar effect can also be achieved with `unbuffer` (comes with `expect`) and `script`.